# sql compare date and particular time

Tags: php, mysql

using php, i have a sql query which works fine, dateentry only has the date such as `2012-03-20`

```
"SELECT dateentry FROM mytable WHERE dateentry >= DATE(CURDATE()) ORDER BY navDisplayNum ASC;"   enter code here
```

but i wish to add time to my query so that the dB entry + 8 am is compared to the current date + time
can anyone lend a hand how to properly handle this problem please

```
"SELECT dateentry FROM mytable WHERE dateentry"." 8:00:00"." >= DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY navDisplayNum ASC;"
```

this attempt produces an error 
*"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '8:00:00 >= DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY navDisplayNum ASC'"*

Comment: `date(curdate())` is totally redundant. curdate already returns just a date value.

Comment: @t q: then Scott Hyndman's answer is perfect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to add time to an existing date, use the [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function. Just putting a time next to an existing date will not work.

Take a look:

```
SELECT dateentry FROM mytable WHERE DATE_ADD(dateentry, INTERVAL 8 hour) >= NOW();
```

Comment: is it possible to use a combination of INTERVAL 1DAY and 8 HOUR with DATE_ADD?

Comment: @tq: Just have a look at the manual, it contains the answer to this question.